# Spring validation has error in XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation

I applied spring validation in my registration page .but the follwing error are shown in my server log of my app engine server.

```
 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
    Line 22 in XML  document from ServletContext resource 
    [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; 
    nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
    lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 30; 
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, 
    but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
```

My code is given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd >


    <beans:bean name="/register" class="com.my.registration.NewUserRegistration">
        <property name="validator">
            <bean class="com.my.validation.UserValidator" />
        </property>
        <beans:property name="formView" value="newuser"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="successView" value="home"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default XML namespace of your document is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc`, therefore you should use namespace prefix for all elements from other namespaces, including elements from `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` namespace:

```
<beans:property name="validator">
    <beans:bean class="com.my.validation.UserValidator" />
</beans:property>
```

Alternatively, you can configure `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` as a default namespace:

```
xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Obviously, in this case you'd need to use namespace prefix for elemetns from `mvc` namespace, if you have any.

**See also:**

- [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)

Answer (score 1):

This does not have the propery XML namespace prefix:

```
<property name="validator">
  <bean class="com.my.validation.UserValidator" />
</property>
```

Use `beans` as the prefix.

Actually I recommend to use the `beans` namespace as the default XML namespace and to make `mvc` an explicit namespace.